# MalformedJsonException when parse a string in java

Tags: java, gson

I have this string that represents a student entity:

```
{\"firstName\":\"Pirlog\",\"lastName\":\"Marcel\",\"year\":3,\"grupa\":\"B4\",\"accountId\":\"c9e4b165-8fdd-4ca2-974e-9b598ddb52bc\",\"id\":\"e577cf18-53bb-4e4e-bce2-b543f1d51f85\"}
```

The Student entity class is:

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int year;
    private String grupa;
    private UUID accountId;
    private UUID id;

    public Student(){

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int year, String grupa, String accountId, String id){
        this.id = UUID.fromString(id);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.year = year;
        this.grupa = grupa;
        this.accountId = UUID.fromString(accountId);
    }
}
```

For parse the string I use this code:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
String p = g.toJson(response1);
Student s = g.fromJson(p.substring(1, p.length() - 1), Student.class);
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

response1 is a httpresponse's body and it represents my string from description.

Exception:

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 2 path $.
    at com.google.gson@2.8.6/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:947)
    at com.google.gson@2.8.6/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson@2.8.6/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
    at com.google.gson@2.8.6/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
    at Marcel/Marcel.controllers.uicontrollers.LoginScreenController.LoginFunction(LoginScreenController.java:42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
Gson g = new Gson();
            String p = g.toJson(response1);
            Student s = g.fromJson(p.substring(1, p.length() - 1), Student.class);
            System.out.println(s.toString());
```

with

```
Gson g = new Gson();
        Reader reader = new StringReader(response1);
        Student s = g.fromJson(reader, Student.class);
        System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Comment: An explanation would be helpful, just in case someone wants to actually learn something instead of just copying & pasting some code from the interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

The `gson` error indicates that you are giving it a malformed JSON string, so it's your JSON you need to examine.

In this line, you are removing braces from your JSON:

```
Student s = g.fromJson(p.substring(1, p.length() - 1), Student.class);
```

Don't do this; the braces are required. Another problem may be that you have some backslashes in your JSON to escape double quotes. Perhaps these are there because of the way you moved the JSON into your question, but you should filter them out before passing the string to `gson`.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862689/gson-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-name-at-line-7-column-4), as well, where the same problem is discussed.